# Show the value of a SELECT COUNT

Tags: php

I am working with RedBeanPHP and I want to know the most repeated values of a column.

I have this:

```
$books = R::getAll('
    SELECT `autor`,
        COUNT(`autor`) AS `value_occurrence` 
    FROM `fichas`
    GROUP BY `autor`
    ORDER BY `value_occurrence` DESC
    LIMIT 10
');

foreach( $books as $book ) {
    echo $book['autor'] . '<br />';
}
```

I also want to display the number of times the value of 'autor' repeats.  For example:

```
John Smith (10)
Jack Sparrow (7)
```

How can I retrieve such value?

Comment: `$book['value_occurrence']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you get info for `author`:

```
echo $book['value_occurrence'];
```

In this case you can use

```
echo $book['autor'] . '(' . $book['value_occurrence'] . ')';
```